# laravel validate Content-Type: application/json request

Tags: json, web-services, laravel, laravel-5

in laravel 5 i made a new request named `ApiRequest`.

```
class ApiRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize() {
      return $this->isJson();
    }
    public function rules()
    {
     return [
            //
            ];
    }
}
```

As you can see i am accepting only json data. And i am receiving the json in controller like this

```
public function postDoitApi(ApiRequest $payload) {
        $inputJson = json_decode($payload->getContent()); 
        $name = $inputJson->name;
}
```

Which is working fine. I am getting data in `$name`. But now i need to validate the input json.
I need to set validation rule in `ApiRequest` for the `name` key like this

```
public function rules()
{
     return [
            'name' => 'required|min:6'
            ];
}
```

Help me to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a validator method instead of rules method:

```
class ApiRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize() {
      return $this->isJson();
    }

    public function validator(){

        //$data = \Request::instance()->getContent();

        $data = json_decode($this->instance()->getContent());

        return \Validator::make($data, [
           'name' => 'required|min:6'
        ], $this->messages(), $this->attributes());
    }

    //what happens if validation fails
    public function validate(){

        $instance = $this->getValidatorInstance();

        if($this->passesAuthorization()){
             $this->failedAuthorization();
        }elseif(!$instance->passes()){
              $this->failedValidation($instance);
        }elseif( $instance->passes()){

        if($this->ajax())
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['success' =>          true]));

        }

   }
}
```

Comment: yes it did work, but the problem is if validation fails then it redirects to home url instead of showing error message. i am passing `['name.required' => 'name is required']` to the $this->messages() but didn't work.

Comment: Please help me to show the error message. Digitlimit

Comment: Okay buddy. Pls give me few minutes. Working on it. Want to create it in my project

Comment: are you trying to get the error message on your AJAX calls?

Comment: Am not sure why you are being directed back to home url , I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel validates AJAX requests the same way. Just make sure you're setting one of these request headers on your request:

`'Accept': 'application/json'`

`'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'`

Answer (score 3):

Validating any headers can be done in clean way two steps:

###### Step 1: Prepare header data to request data in `prepareForValidation` method.

```php
public function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        "content_type" => $this->headers->get("Content-type"),
    ]);
}
```

###### Step 2: Apply any validation rules that you want, (Here, you want your data exact to be `application/json`. so

```php
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        "content_type" => "required|in:application/json",
    ];
}
```

Complete Example looks like:

```php
/**
 * Class LoginRequest
 *
 * @package App\Requests
 */
class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->merge([
            "content_type" => $this->headers->get("Content-type"),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            "content_type" => "required|in:application/json",
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    return $inputJson->toArray();
```

and then pass to validator

```
    $name = ['name'=>'er'];
    $rules = array('name' => 'required|min:4');
    $validation = Validator::make($name,$rules);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put following function in your `ApiRequest` form request.

```
public function validator(){

    return \Validator::make(json_decode($this->getContent(),true), $this->rules(), $this->messages(), $this->attributes());    

}
```

Comment: go this 
ErrorException in AuthController.php line 17:
Declaration of Packr\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::validate() should be compatible with Packr\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = Array, array $customAttributes = Array)

Comment: @SudiptaDhara can you try replacing `Request` with `\Illuminate\Http\Request` in first function arguments? And are you sure you are using same code as above without changing visibility or arguments any way?